# How to use quasi-Newton methods to solve a non-linear system?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, algorithm, difference-equations

Consider the following function, for $\mathbf{x}=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$
$$
F(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{e^{A_k\mathbf{x}}-e^{B_k\mathbf{x}}}{C_k\mathbf{x}}-\mathbf{b}
$$
where $\{A_k\}$, $\{B_k\}$ and $\{C_k\}$ are $n\times n$ matrices. Given an initial guess $\mathbf{x}_0$, what is the best way to find an approximation to the non-negative zeros of $F$, i.e, solve $F(\mathbf{x})=0$?

I have heard about quasi-Newton methods, but I am not too sure how to implement them in Mathematics. Any ideas?

**My attempt:** Using `NSolve`, I define the following `solver` function

```
solver = Function[data,

   n = Length[data];

   T[ki_] := SparseArray[Join[
      Table[
       Sequence @@ {Band[{1, k}] -> 1, Band[{k, 1}] -> 1}, {k, 1, 
        ki + 1}],
      Table[
       Sequence @@ {Band[{1, n - k + 1}] -> 1, 
         Band[{n - k + 1, 1}] -> 1}, {k, 1, ki}]],
     {n, n}];
   Tk[ki_] := SparseArray[Join[
      Table[
       Sequence @@ {Band[{1, k}] -> ki + 1 - k, 
         Band[{k, 1}] -> ki + 1 - k}, {k, 1, ki + 1}],
      Table[
       Sequence @@ {Band[{1, n - k + 1}] -> ki - k, 
         Band[{n - k + 1, 1}] -> ki - k}, {k, 1, ki}]],
     {n, n}];

   xv = Table[x[i], {i, n}];

   NSolve[
      Sum[(E^(Tk[k] . xv) - 
           E^-(Tk[k + 1] + T[k]) . xv))/(T[k] . xv), {k, 
         0, (n - 1)/2}] == data, xv][[1]] // Values

   ];
```

However, running `solver[data]` gets stuck for a [data set like this](https://justpaste.it/59qtt), for example.

Comment: Quasi Newton methods are methods that do not use the inverse of the Jacobian to find a zero. However, if the Jacobian is available you can use Newton.

Comment: FindRoot or NSolve or NMinimize might all be appropriate.

Comment: I have written my attempt with specific matrices and data. Can you please take a look?

Comment: Only assembling the data matrices `Tk` and `T` and the resulting symbolic expression takes an enormous amount of time. If you have any intent of solving the problem you will need to improve on that first. Symbolic may not be the way to go. The motivation of the problem is not clear to me, and I would spend time refining the motivation. You seemed to be trying to calculate some type of derivative. Can you take advantage of that?

Comment: More on the problem in hand, do you really mean exponential of vectors? Do the division means entrywise division? If so, then you will need to Thread the equality `==` to evaluate into the the equations you are trying to find a zero for. There is a missing parenthesis on the function definition near the second exponential.