# Finding only non-negative roots with FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, findinstance

Given an arbitrary function F, how do I force `FindRoot` to look only for non-negative roots, returning nothing otherwise?

Comment: From the documentation, `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, xstart, xmin, xmax}] searches for a solution, stopping the search if x ever gets outside the range xmin to xmax.`

Comment: Edit your question to provide a concrete example of a function that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: @BobHanlon can you do that for vectors as well? Something like `{x[0], x[1], ... , x[n]}`.

Comment: Try `FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {{x[0], x0start, x0min, x0max}, {x[1], x1start, x1min, x1max}, ..., {x[n], xnstart, xnmin, xnmax}}]`

Answer (score 1):

`FindRoot` only looks for one root and does not admit constraints. Use `NSolve` instead, as in

```
NSolve[(x + 1) (x - 1) == 0 && x > 0, x]
```

which returns

> {{x -> 1.}}

Comment: For a vector, it seems incredibly slow compared to FindRoot. Compare, for example, with [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282337/how-to-use-quasi-newton-methods-to-solve-a-non-linear-system). Can we choose a first guess?

Comment: It has to be slow as it it attempting to find all roots, and not just one, like FindRoot. You can also recast the root finding as a constrained minimization and go for that if you would like more control, at the expense of at times getting stuck at a local minimum and never finding a root.

Comment: Thank you! [This is the data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282337/how-to-use-quasi-newton-methods-to-solve-a-non-linear-system) and the system I have in mind. I tried using `NSolve`, but to no avail. Hence, using `FindRoot`. Would you like to take a look?